# Sencha Touch dataview and initialize doesnt work together

Tags: extjs, initialization, touch, dataview

I have a problem with my code. I want to use Sencha Touch DataView and everything works fine until I try put initialize event. When I put it, intialize event, my dataview cannot be generated. Here is my code. Can you help me :)?

```
Ext.define("xxx.view.Spread", {
extend: 'Ext.DataView',
xtype: 'xxxspread',
id: 'spreadForm',   
config : {
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    store: {
        //autoLoad: true,
        fields: ["name", "desc"],
        data: [
            {name: 'test',  desc: "testtest"},
            {name: 'test',  desc: "test"},
        ],
    },


    itemTpl: '<img src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1089012240/sencha-logo_normal.png" /><h1>{name}</h1><p>{desc}</p><div style="clear: both"></div>',

},  

initialize: function() {
    console.log("init");
},


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to make a config for your `listeners`, and catch the `initialize` event there.

```
config: {
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    store : ...
    //More config here
    listeners: {
        initialize: function() { console.log('init'); }
    }
}
```